# Finding and replacing blank lines regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, replace

I'm using Notepad++ and basically I want to find all ***blank lines that don't contain text*** using Notepad++ regex. I know that there is a simpler way of doing this by using 'textfx,' but I'm looking for an expression to do this.  Here is an example below with the symbols shown.

```
< ?php **CRLF**
**CRLF**                        *<- REMOVE THIS* 
$xxx = $_POST['xxx'];**CRLF**
$xxx = $_POST['xxx'];**CRLF**
$xxx = $_POST['xxx'];**CRLF**
**CRLF**                        *<- REMOVE THIS* 
**CRLF**                        *<- REMOVE THIS* 
if ($xxx)**CRLF**
{**CRLF**
```

Answer (score 25):

Not a regular expression, but Notepad++ 6.3.2 has a number of ways of removing blank lines without using a regular expression.

Menu => **Edit** => **Line operations** => **Remove empty lines**

Menu => **Edit** => **Line operations** => **Remove empty lines (containing blank characters)**

Menu => **TextFx** => **TextFx Edit** => **Delete blank lines**

Menu => **TextFx** => **TextFx Edit** => **Delete surplus blank lines**

The two TextFx methods only delete empty lines, but they can be preceded with either of:

Menu => **Edit** => **Blank operations** => **Trim trailing spaces**

Menu => **TextFx** => vTextFx Edit** => **Trim trailing spaces**

Comment: Way helpful, thanks!

Comment: It may have been what he wanted, but this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

I've only been able to do this by using the "Extended" search mode in the Replace dialog (not "Regular expression" mode).

The search term I use is `\r\n\r\n`, and I replace it with `\r\n`.  You have to keep repeating this until there were no changes, if there can be even more newlines in a row.

I also wish there was a better RegEx engine in Notepad++ with the ability to do multi-line searches.

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick reply. but when i use \r\n and replace with nothing all the code moves to one line anyway to solve this?

Comment: @keith - Sorry, I already edited my post -- you need to search for two sequential newline sequences and replace them with a single one.

Comment: This is good if you have done "trim trailing and save" first. Otherwise whitespace will spoil it.

Answer (score 9):

I just did find ^\r\n and replace with nothing

Answer (score 4):

Its possible, but not directly.

In short, go to the search, use the regex `^$` to search, check "mark lines" (in the current version there is a seperate mark tab in the search dialogue) and click "Find all". It results in bookmarks for all those lines.

In the search menu there is a point "delete bookmarked lines" thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Without using TextFx I don't think you can. There's no way I know of to tell the Find and Replace in Notepad++ that you want to delete the line. You can find all those lines by searching for '^$' (minus the quotes) with Regular Expression turned on. But the best you can do is replace it with an empty string, not a delete.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad v6.2.2 there is option called Extended(\t\n......)
and In replace box, provide \r\n it works fine