# Trying to manipulate lines in a document with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, sentence

I have a text document that was poorly formatted for my purposes, and I had to make some changes. But now I have another problem, which is a lot of sentences "stranded" on their own, like this:

```
    \n
    [some text here, bla bla bla.]\n
    \n
```

Does anyone know of a way to represent a sentence with regular expressions? I want to join these sentences with the paragraph above or below. 
I swear I searched both Google and this site before asking.

Edit: 
Sorry, I lost access to my original post, and couldn't comment on Amber's answer. I'll register an account for future questions. 
Plus, I neglected to mention the fact that I'm using Notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looking for any pair of newlines with only a single terminating punctuation mark between them? E.g.

```
\n([^\n.?!]+[.?!][^\n.?!]*)\n
```

and then just replace that with...

```
'\n\1 '
```

Comment: Amber: I tried this, but sadly it didn't work. Might it be beyond the capabilities of Notepad++? But it makes a good starting point, thank you very much.
(I wanted to make this an answer to your post, but I couldn't find out how... Maybe I should just give up computers.)

Comment: @computer_genius Notepad++ is not able to handle regexes over multiple rows. It looks at each row and remove newline characters before. But there is the extended search mode where you can use `\r` and `\n` (but no regular expressions). See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381444/finding-and-replacing-blank-lines-regex-in-notepad/5381649#5381649) about finding empty rows