# Notepad++ matchin end of line in regexp

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to transform this

```
a

b


b
```

into this

```
a
b
b
```

number of empty lines is variable and can be pretty huge. Empty lines contains spaces. I want to use a regexp like `\r\n( *\r\n)+`, but notepad++ seems not to like those special characters in regexp, tryed also `\\r\\n( *\\r\\n)+`

**Please note that empty lines may contain spaces, so the correct regexp would be something like `\\r\\n( *\\r\\n)+`**

Comment: I don't know about Notepad++, but Usually `$` represents a beginning of line and `^` represents an end of line...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding and replacing blank lines regex in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381444/finding-and-replacing-blank-lines-regex-in-notepad)

Comment: Ilya, it's the other way round.

Comment: This is not directly possible with regex in Notepad, because the regexes are limited to only one row (newlines are removed by the regex engine), but you can see my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5381649/626273) or of course the other answers to that question.

Comment: @stema very close to the other question, but I have also spaces and other question has no regexp answer too.

Comment: @Paolo: You should have mentioned in your original question that there are spaces in those blank lines.

Comment: @Paolo, there is no pure single regex answer to this question for Notepad++

Comment: @BoltClock I did, as long I realized it was relevant I mentioned it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do 'replace all' multiple times on

```
\r\n\r\n -> \r\n
```

That's with 'Extended' option selected, not 'Regular expression'.

If the empty line contains spaces, then first replace all lines with only spaces with nothing using regex: `^\s+$` -> `''`. Then to the extended replacement above.

**Alternatively:**

You can also replace all `\r\n` with some sequence of characters that doesn't exists in the document, e.g. `###` then use the following regex replacement : `'###(\s*###)+' -> '###'` and finally replace back the sequence ('###') with `\r\n`.

Comment: Actually "empty" lines contains spaces.

Comment: If `\r\n(\r\n)+` doesn't match, then very likely `\r\n\r\n` neither.

Comment: Replacing spaces with nothing will screw all the lines with spaces and somethin else maybe `^\s+$` -> `''` will do

Comment: There is absolutely no way to do this in one pass; this answer is the closest you can get.

Comment: @Paolo with the regular expression option it does work, I just tested it.

Comment: @Paolo: yes I forgot the anchors. It's corrected now. Thanks!