# Notepad ++ Blank Line removal

Tags: notepad++

I want to get rid of blank lines.

Only solutions I see online are: `\r\n\r\n`

Firstly, I don't know what that is supposed to do.  Secondly, it doesn't work anyways.

**Change from:**

```
1234

1234

1234
```

**Change to:**

```
1234
1234
1234
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing empty lines in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866034/removing-empty-lines-in-notepad)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381444/finding-and-replacing-blank-lines-regex-in-notepad/16882536#16882536

Answer (score 3):

There is even a function for that in the menu, you find it under

- Edit -> Line Operations -> Remove empty lines
- Edit -> Line Operations -> Remove empty lines (Containing blank characters)

The second option removes also lines that contain only spaces.