# Line numbers only for active lines

Tags: notepad++

Many compilers will only take into account active lines when counting line numbers, and ignore those who are empty or entirely commented out, whereas NPP is counting them. In case of an error, it means I cannot find the incriminated line and have to use search.

Is there a way to only count active lines in NPP?

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093275/34092 ?

Comment: It's not about removing empty lines, it's about abstracting them while counting line numbers

Comment: Npp is an editor, not a compiler. This can't be done.

Comment: Suggest use development environment suitable for your language. It will integrate the compilation and messages into the code. The leading development  environment are technology specific and require extensive experience. For students I suggest simple `VS Code` or `Eclipse`.

Comment: What forms of `comments` can you find? Are there multiline comments? What are the syntax for both cases?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I guess is that npp doesn't know implicitly what an active line to a compiler means.

As @mjWills mentioned, I think you can achieve this by

- removing the blank lines (which will be ignored by compiler)
- removing the comments etc (by using regex, bookmark lines, remove bookmarked lines from menu)

depends on the language and compiler you are using ..

Comment: How is this answering the question? It should be a comment.

Comment: He wants NPP to show active lines. I just showed him my solution. It's too long for a comment I guess. Just specific for his use case I guess. Maybe I'll move it comment later.